# Store Several Elements of a Page to a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I need to store several text elements of a page to a JSON object, however I am not being able to do this in protractor due to asynchronicity.

Here is one sample of my code, which is inside a loop of `element.all()`:

```
var json = {};
e[i].element(by.css(".nome_projeto")).getText().then(function(text){
    json.nome = text;
});
e[i].element(by.css(".nome_cliente")).getText().then(function(text){
    json.cliente = text;
});
e[i].element(by.css('.data_fim')).getText().then(function(text){
    json.data = text;
});
console.log(json);
list.push(json);
```

However, when I log, my JSON object is undefined, and I can only access it inside the `then`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can resolve multiple promises "at once" with `protractor.promise.all()`:

```
protractor.promise.all([
    e[i].element(by.css(".nome_projeto")).getText(),
    e[i].element(by.css(".nome_cliente")).getText(),
    e[i].element(by.css('.data_fim')).getText()
]).then(function (texts) {
    var obj = {};

    obj.nome = texts[0];
    obj.cliente = texts[1];
    obj.data = texts[2];

    console.log(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I see Italian names :D we could speak in Italian :D

By the way, I suggest you to change it with this code, in order to manage all the promises:

```
var json = {};
var promises = [
    e[i].element(by.css(".nome_projeto")).getText(),
    e[i].element(by.css(".nome_cliente")).getText(),
    e[i].element(by.css('.data_fim')).getText()
];
protractor.promise.all(promises).then(function(data) {
    json.nome = data[0];
    json.cliente = data[1];
    json.data = data[2];
    list.push(json);
});
```

It should work